# How to set Password Expiration Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-sql-server

As shown in the screenshot below, we don't see an option to set password expiration date. **Question**: How can we set a password expiration date of an existing login using `SSMS` or `t-sql`. We are using `Azure SQL Managed Instance` but it probably would be the same on on-prem servers as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/285983/get-sql-login-expiration-date.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set them in SQL; they come from Windows (on Windows) and/or Active Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-ver16

> Some combinations of policy options are not supported.
>
> If MUST_CHANGE is specified, CHECK_EXPIRATION and CHECK_POLICY must be
> set to ON. Otherwise, the statement fails.
>
> If CHECK_POLICY is set to OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION cannot be set to ON.
> An ALTER LOGIN statement that has this combination of options will
> fail.
>
> Setting CHECK_POLICY = ON prevents the creation of passwords that are:
>
> Null or empty
>
> Same as name of computer or login
>
> Any of the following: "password", "admin", "administrator", "sa",
> "sysadmin"
>
> ***The security policy might be set in Windows, or might be received from
> the domain. To view the password policy on the computer, use the Local
> Security Policy MMC snap-in (secpol.msc).***

Use secpol.msc (go to the Windows command line with administrator rights and type "secpol.msc" then hit Enter)